# Semi-selfservice user registration

Tags: user-management, user-accounts, ejabberd

I don't want to have wide-open registration on my server so I don't have to deal with spam accounts, but at the same time I don't want to have to manually add accounts for each person I invite to my ejabberd server.  Is there a way to have one-time registration URLs or one-time codes to input on the registration page that I can generate and hand out, and then each person can set up their own account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by registration page you mean [mod_register_web](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#mod-register-web) it doesn't seem to have such functionality out of the box. However, ejabberd supports multiple [authentication](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#authentication) methods of which most enables you to code a custom registration page with one-time registration codes.

If you simply need to prevent registrations from total strangers and don't have the skills for creating an own registration page, a simple option would be adding a *reverse proxy* with password protection in front of Web Admin BOSH HTTPS port `5281` including mod_register_web's `https://example.org:5281/register/`:

1. Make the ejabberd_http module only listen on `localhost`:

   ```
   port: 5281
       ip: "127.0.0.1"
       module: ejabberd_http
       web_admin: true
       http_bind: true
       tls: true
       certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/server.pem"
   ```
2. Add a (TLS protected) *reverse proxy* (e.g. [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) / [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)) to serve `https://localhost:5281/register/` on `https://example.org:anyport/register/`.
3. Password protect the proxy with HTTP *basic authentication*. (This won't prevent using the same password multiple times.)